# Python 3.8 32 bit. Creating a task manager from user input

Tags: python

So I have this code that i am trying to create a task manager out of that takes user input and puts it in a list inside of a new file. When I run it and type exit it gives me this error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instnaces of 'str' and 'int'.

Here is the code:

```
print('WELCOME TO YOUR TASK MANAGER!')

filename = input('What would you like your filename to be: \n(Please type \'.txt\' at the end of the 
name)');

tasks = []
with open(filename, 'w+') as f:
prompt = 'Please enter what you need to do: \n(separated by commas and a space. Ex: laundry, clean) \n When you are done puting in tasks please type \'exit\' '
user_input = f.write(input(prompt).strip())

while (user_input != 'exit'):
    tasks.append(user_input)
    user_input = input(prompt).strip()


tasks.sort()

print('\nAlphabetical order:')
for task in tasks:
    print(task)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/grega/Documents/Intro to programming/Fin_Proj/assign_proj1.py", line 15, in <module>
    tasks.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line:

```
user_input = f.write(input(prompt).strip())
```

you assign the return value of `f.write`, which is the number of characters written to the file (an `int`) to `user_input`.

Then, in you first loop, you append this int to `tasks`.

After that, you append strings to this list. So, when you try to sort it, you get an error, as you can't compare integers and strings.

You probably meant, instead of `user_input = f.write(input(prompt).strip())`:

```
user_input = input(prompt).strip()
f.write(user_input)
```

Comment: That did fix the error issue. Thank you.   Any idea on why when I am running the code and inputting tasks to do it only writes the first task to the file?

Comment: That's because you don't `write` them in the loop. Also, note that the loop must be part of the `with open(filename, 'w+') as f:` block. As the indentation of your pasted code is messed up, it is difficult to guess how your real code looks.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a variable to

```
f.write(input(prompt).strip())
```

which returns the number of characters written to the file which is an integer. Therefore, when you call

```
tasks.sort()
```

you are trying to sort integers and strings which leads to the error.

You probably meant to do

```
user_input = input(prompt).strip()
f.write(iuser_input)
```